# Need to clear shared prefrences while reinstall

Tags: android

My application start with Login. At time of login I am starting one service, and redirecting to another activity as Home. During this i am using SharedPreferences to directly launch Home activity instead of Login activity again. But when I am reinsatlling APK service stops. So i am thinking of clearing SharedPreferences while reinstalling so that apllication launch to Login activity instead of Home. So that user Login to appliaction again and service start again.

Comment: Hope this is giving an idea what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install an application, there is `ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` broadcast sent, however an installed application does not receive it.

When you uninstall application, it is not even called.

Summary - it's impossible to catch those events from your own application.

Answer (score 2):

A shared preference and sqlite db doesnt get removed on a reinstall. 
To delete them, go to 
**`Settings-->Appications-->Manage Applications-->Click on you application-->Click on "Clear Data"`** on emulator. this will clear the data stored.